# How can I access my AppUser properties that are references to other objects? (ASP.NET/EFCore)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an AppUser class that inherits from IdentityUser and contains an Inventory object:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public InventoryModel? Inventory { get; set; }
    }
```

I've been using this line to get the current user with all their properties:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Any primitive data types I put in AppUser can be accessed this way, but it seems to be lazy loading and not bringing the inventory along with it. I have manually queried my database and I see that the user I'm getting has an Inventory.InventoryId of 14 (primary key identifier for the Inventory class), but when I use the above statement to get the user, their Inventory is always null.

Is there some kind of ".Include()" that can be used with GetUserAsync? Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: Nope, not with `UserManager` but you can always inject `ApplicationDbContext` and include any navigation property you want.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing, and it works, but it feels very hacky. I have to use the UserManager to get the current (lazy loaded) user, then take that ID and use it to pull the user from the context with all of the includes. Can't _believe_ there isn't a better way to do that.

Comment: You can bypass `GetUserAsync`, you can define that the navigation is always loaded, or you can `context.Entry(entity).Navigation("Inventory").Load[Async]()` which is useful if your FK is based on shadow properties and is also how `ILazyLoader` works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this same issue looking for a quick fix:

As Eldar suggested, I injected the `ApplicationDbContext` and then did something like this:

```csharp
//get lazy-loaded current user using the usermanager

var lazyUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);


//get current user with includes using the ApplicationDbContext
//and the Id from the current user I already grabbed

var user = await _context.AppUsers.Where(u => u.Id == lazyUser.Id)
                                  .Include(u => u.Inventory)
                                  .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

It's pretty inelegant but technically it accomplish what I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: You don't need `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)`. Knowing the Id of the user is enough to query it from context.